# Require js caches the setup file which sets up the urlArgs bust

Tags: javascript, caching, requirejs

I have a knockout/require app and am struggling with the caching of one particular file. Sadly it is the file that busts the cache for all other javascript files. The setup may be slightly odd:

Each view simply binds a knockout view model. It requires the require library and the main script for the particular area of the system:

```
<script data-main="scripts/user" src="~/Scripts/lib/require.js"></script>
```

The scripts/user.js file required above requires the common file (containing the require setup) and the main viewmodel script:

```
require(['./Common'], function (common) {
    require(['userMain']);
})
```

The scripts/user/userMain.js file binds the viewmodel and requires anything needed at the view level (such as custom binding handlers).

```
define(function (require) {
    require(['ko', 'userViewModel'], function (ko, userViewModel) {
        var userVm = new userViewModel(false);
        userVm.initialise();

        // bound to the wrapper to stop jquery dialog bindings being applied twice
        ko.applyBindings(userVm, document.getElementById('pageWrapper'));
    });
});
```

Then we have common.js:

```
require.config({
    baseUrl: './',
    paths: {
        'userMain': './Scripts/user/Main',
        'userAjax': './Scripts/user/userAjax',
        'userBasicDetails': './Scripts/user/userBasicDetails',
        'userExchangesModel': './Scripts/user/userExchangesModel',
        'userModel': './Scripts/user/userModel',
        'userReportAccessModel': './Scripts/user/userReportAccessModel',
        'usersModel': './Scripts/user/usersModel',
        'userViewModel': './scripts/user/userViewModel',
    ... etc
    ,
    urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
```

each script within the folder then requires anything it needs within its own model.

The script structure is then setup as so:

```
scripts\common.js
scripts\user.js
scripts\user\main.js
scripts\user\userAjax
scripts\user\etc...
```

This setup allows me to reference scripts from other folders without specifying where the  file is anywhere other than in common.js. The downside is that all js files have a reference in common but I can live with that.
As an example there are 4 or 5 folders at the same level as 'user' ('scripts\report\', 'scripts\client' etc) and if I want to create
a user model from any of the scripts within those folders I can simply "define (['userModel'], function (userModel)" and common will tell require where to go and find that file. This system works well, allowing me to move files around at will and only change their path in one place.

The problem comes when I add new scripts or change paths in common.js. Whilst all others are bust every request due to the setup
in common the common file itself gets cached so I have to bust users' chrome caches before the new common.js file gets picked up. This is obviously a big issue at delivery time - pages fail as they cannot find the new script because it doesn't exist in the same folder and common has been cached.

Can anyone suggest a way of automatically busting common.js or moving the path config into a separate required file so that the urlArgs bust will do it for me?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before the `script` element that loads RequireJS, add the following code:

```
<script>
  require = {
      urlArgs: "bust=" + (new Date()).getTime()
  };
</script>
```

RequireJS will pick this up as its initial configuration and *any* module it loads, through `data-main` or any other way, will be required with a `bust` parameter.

It is probably best to remove `urlArgs` from your subsequent call to `require.config`. It will override the earlier option so the value of the `bust` will change. Usually, modules are loaded once and only once by RequireJS so it *should* not happen that the same module is loaded by the same page with two different `bust` values. But there are scenarios I'm unsure about (for instance, using `require.undef` to undefine a module). Removing the later `urlArgs` would avoid bad surprises.

Comment: Many thanks, I cannot tell for sure until I deliver that this has worked but I certainly see the bust argument at the end of the troublesome file which is everything I wanted from this question. I was slightly disturbed to have to add this to multiple views but it is a lot better than the alternative! Many thanks again.